# Using Google maps sdk between a framework and app that consumes framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

We are creating a cocoa touch framework to be consumed by an app. The app uses the google maps framework. The client also wants us to use the google maps framework in parts of the framework that we are creating, but they also don't want us to include the google maps framework to avoid dependency collision.

I know we could change the namespace, but is there any other way?

1. is there any way to expose our framework to classes within the app?
2. is there any way to include the google maps sdk into our framework project and not have it included in the build?
3. any other ideas?

I'm stumped

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I m stuck in same situation. Please let me know! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Better to distribute your framework with `cocoapods`(Private pods that uses your private repository) then add `GoogleMaps` as dependency to your pod. Then recommend client to use `cocoapods`.

You can refer creating pod spec here http://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_spec_create

Create private pod https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html